# Сделать из csv файла список с кортежами

Tags: python, файлы, csv, списки

Ребят помогите буду очень благодарен, 2 дня мучаюсь ,я начинающий в Python
Имеется csv файл:

```
Pink Floyd | The Dark Side Of The Moon | 1973 | psychodelic rock | 43:00
Eminem | Recovery | 2007 | rap | 21:00
```

Задача в том чтобы создать список,

Нужно создать кортеж, в котoром будет еще 2 кортежа. 
В первом кортеже - название и во втором кортеже - информация.
Все внешние кортежи должны находиться  в одном большом списке.
После чего нужно будет находить разные элемента из списка по названию и показывать всю информацию этого элемента

Пример :

```
music = [(("Pink Floyd", "The Dark Side Of The Moon"), (1973, "psychodelic 
 rock", "43:00")),
     (("Britney Spears", "Baby One More Time"), (1999, "pop", "42:20"))]
```

Вот что пытаюсь сделать я:

```
import csv

with open('music.csv', 'r') as f:
read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
read_csv
music = []


for row in read_csv:
    music.append(row)
```

Выходит списки в списке

```
[['Pink Floyd ', ' The Dark Side Of The Moon ', ' 1973 ', ' psychodelic rock ', ' 43:00'], ['Eminem ', ' Recovery ', ' 2007 ', ' rap ', ' 21:00']]
```

Как вставить эти два кортежа и взять их в один общий кортеж? и как дальше искать слова по кортежам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы говорите про кортежи, но почему-то работаете со списками. Я вас не понимаю. Хотите кортежи - делайте кортежи!

```
import csv

tuples = []

with open('music.csv', 'r') as f:
    read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")

    for row in read_csv:
        row = tuple(row)
        tuples.append(row)

tuples = tuple(tuples)

for x in tuples:
    print(x)
    print(type(x))

print(type(tuples))
```

А вашу задачу можно решить так:

```
import csv

music = []

with open('music.csv', 'r') as f:
    read_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")

    for row in read_csv:
        artist = row[0]
        album = row[1]
        year = row[2]
        genre = row[3]
        time = row[4]

        nametuple = (artist, album)
        infotuple = (year, genre, time)
        globaltuple = (nametuple, infotuple)

        music.append(globaltuple)

print(music)
```

Comment: Логику вашего кода понял

Comment: @ValekPotapov обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вроде все так просто , а додуматься не мог. Очень выручили меня! Благодарен